# Copula density function

Tags: self-study, density-function, copula, bivariate

In the equation $h_t(x,y|...) = ...$, can anyone explain me why the first derivatives of the marginal distributions are included? $H_t$ is a distribution function and $h_t$ its density function.
[image: Distribution function]
[image: Copula density]

Using the relation between distribution and density function I can't get it to make sense.

$$f(x,y)=\frac{\partial ^2 F(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}\,.$$

Comment: This question is not standalone. I doubt many readers will go through the trouble of trying to answer your question. If you want to increase the likelihood of getting an answer, you should consider making your question standalone, so that readers don't have to access an external site in order to understand your question (also, if the link changes or the file gets removed, this post will become entirely useless).

Comment: I have removed the link, and tried to explain my question better.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $F$ is the distribution function of a bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$ when

$${\Pr}(a\lt X \le b,\, c\lt Y \le d) = F(b,d) - F(a,d) - F(b,c) + F(a,c)$$

for all real numbers $a\le b,\, c\le d$.

Suppose $F$ is continuously twice-differentiable. Let $f(x,y) = \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial y}F(x,y)$ be its mixed second derivative. Being a continuous function, it is integrable, and--applying [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)--we may exploit the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) to integrate twice:

$$\eqalign{
\iint_{(a,b]\times(c,d]} f(x,y) dxdy &= \int_a^b \left(\int_c^d \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x,y)\right) dy \right)dx \\
&= \int_a^b \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x,d) - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x,c)\right)dx \\
&= F(b,d) - F(a,d) - \left(F(b,c) - F(a,c)\right) \\
&= {\Pr}(a\lt X \le b,\, c\lt Y \le d).
}$$

This exhibits $f$ as a valid density function for $(X,Y)$.

A little extra care is needed when $f$ is not continuous (but only integrable), but even so, this case demonstrates why the two partial derivatives appear.